# Multiline toolbar Ext JS 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4, multiline

Is there a standardized way to create a multiline toolbar? I'm dinamically loading the items and they are usually more than enough to make the toolbar overflow. But I don't want the overflow functionality, I just want the items to span several lines. As the items are loaded dinamically, I can not create several stacked toolbars beforehand. An observation: I switched the layout from the implicit default 'hbox' to 'auto' and the items do span several lines, but then, features like separators have undesired collateral efects, like having only one item or separator on each line, and also different looks in different browsers.

I could dinamically calculate the suposed total width of the items and divide by the max desired width of a toolbar to obtain the number of toolbars I need, but I don't know exactly at what point the items get a valid useful width.

This is an old question posted by someone else sometime ago. I'm re-asking because perhaps with the latests releases of Ext JS, they shiped 'undocumentedly' the sooo needed layout solution for this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an out of box component that can do all of the things you want.

The default toolbar layout of HBox just places everything horizontally spaced. 
If you know that you need more space you can always put in a container with whatever layout you want for it's items. You can get creative and nest all kinds of layouts.

Personally I think this would end up looking ugly. Perhaps there is a better solution with an alternative approach to your design needs.

Comment: what does this have to do with tooltips?

Comment: I updated from Ext JS 4.2.0 to 4.2.1 and now my tooltips show OK, so I can live with the way the toolbar looks with the 'auto' layout instead of 'hbox', spaning multiple rows. Perhaps the Ext JS developers can take this common request as a challenge and create a multiline layout for future releases. However I will give a try to items wrapped into containers. Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using ellipsis to shorten the text in the items in order to fit more items in the same space, but tooltips were buggy in previous version.

Comment: I also added 'text-align: left' to the toolbar and now it looks even greater. But I can not use separators, they make the toolbar look destroyed.